# Sound drops out in MP4 video playback using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, video, vlc

I'm having problems with MP4 video playback (MP4 files recorded from my Android).  With the "Videos" app., the sound drops out after about 2 seconds.  Another 2 seconds of sound can be heard by clicking somewhere else on the timeline.

I tried installing VLC; however in that case, the sound works, but the video freezes.

I tried installing GNOME MPlayer, and the sound plays for longer than with "Videos", but still drops out after several seconds.  Sound can be heard for another few seconds by clicking elsewhere on the video playback bar (timeline).

My computer is an Acer Aspire-One Netbook 722-0828

I was pretty happy with Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  The forced upgrade to 14.04LTS has been a nightmare thus far.

Answer (score 0):

On a **desktop** computer, I ran into the same issue while playing YouTube videos on Chromium web browser on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS. I tried many things which didn't work.

At the end, I simply disconnected and reconnected the speaker/audio port at desktop maindboard and the problem got resolved.

I know you are having problem on a laptop, but I thought this solution might help someone.